# Laravel and JavaScript : reflect changes in browser

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, gulp

I'm new to a project which is using PHP, Laravel. One of the blade templates(`projectRoot/resources/views/thisTemplate.blade.php`) calls a method from a JavaScript file (`projectRoot/allJs/src/this.js`). I made a change in this.js, but it did not get reflected in browser. The gulpfile in `projectRoot/allJs/gulpfile.js` has the following task.

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
return gulp.src(['src/this.js'])
.pipe(gp_concat('main.js'))
.pipe(gp_uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('../public/js/allFiles'));
});
```

Am I missing anything in the gulpfile? Or what gulp command do I need to run to reflect js changes in the browser?

Comment: Have you run `gulp watch`?

Comment: I tried to install `browser-sync` and create a task which has `browserSync.reload()` method. A default task initiates browserSync with `browserSync.init({server: baseDir: "localhosturl"}); gulp.watch("src/*.js", ['js-watch']);` But when I run `gulp default`, `localhost:3000` opens up with `Cannot GET /` error